# attempting to understand gas limits, and why I'm getting infinite gas and extremely high gas fees for the constructor function

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Coin {

    address public minter;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;


    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);


    constructor() {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }


    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == minter);
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }


    error InsufficientBalance(uint requested, uint available);


    function send(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        if (amount > balances[msg.sender])
            revert InsufficientBalance({
                requested: amount,
                available: balances[msg.sender]
            });

        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        emit Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    }
}
```

While scrolling and attempting to understand ALL aspects of solidity, I can't understand gas fees. Why they say infinite and why it says the "constructor" function is so high.

Comment: When does what say "infinite"? Are you aiming to deploy the contract in an emulator (Remix VM, Hardhat, ...), interact with this contract that is already deployed on some public network, ... ? What value are you expecting to be lower? ... As the quetion is currently written, it's hard to understand what goals you're trying to achieve. Please edit and clarify.

Comment: I apologize for my ambiguous question, I'm using Remix, and the interface (Remix) usually gives estimates of gas, but it tells me infinite next to the mint, and send function. and next to the constructor it has an extremely high gas estimate. I really just want to understand how to limit, and change the gas fees.

Answer (score 0):

Remix IDE contains an estimator that is still in active development (February 2023), and it's not perfect yet.

In some cases it's simply not able to estimate the amount of gas that the function is going to consume, and then it shows `Infinity` or `undefined`.

For example, it can currently estimate simple assigning to the value, but it's not yet able to estimate increasing the value:

[image: assigning]
[image: increasing]

But it doesn't mean that the actual consumption is going to be infinite.

Comment: I have some code I'm working on and I recieved this error

"Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? 
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":6193543822304242}"

When I attempted to force the transaction the gas fee was astronomically high ( around $600) I would like to send you the code so maybe you can see if the same issue shows up on your end?